# RxJS and WebWorkers

Tags: angularjs, system.reactive, web-worker, rxjs

Quick question

If I have a `WebWorker` that has a function that returns an `Observable<Any>` back to the UI code, if I then subscribe to the Observable, is the observable running on the UI thread or the `WebWorker` thread?

I ask this question because I am writing an Angular2 app with RxJS, and to improve performance I want some of the hard-working Observables to run  within WebWorkers, passing a stream of results over to the UI thread

Comment: Your  post has no question, and no code sample you're trying to make to work.

Comment: @shershen Please read the question again. It contains all the necessary information (only thing missing is a question mark :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your web worker is sending an observable back to your main thread via a message.

Messages are intended to be used both ways, you can't send objects that expose functionality.

The solution is to have your webworker post messages, and then have a main-thread service handle those messages and pipe them into a Subject, which it exposes to your application as an IObservable.

Keep on mind that web worker messaging doesn't support channels, so you'll need to apply your own discriminator if you use messages on multiple areas of your app.

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample with similar architecture? I'd like to understand the terms ( main-thread service vs application )

Comment: so you are saying that the only objects that can move between the web worker and the main thread are simple data objects. Is that because they need to be serialised ? Thanks

Comment: @Dean For all intents and purposes, yes, just data objects. Essentially you'd have a bit of code in your main thread that subscribes to `onmessage` and sends the data it received into a `Subject` via `onNext()`. The part of your app that needs to display this information would subscribe to that subject to receive updates.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that's great infi

Comment: @RichardSzalay - The OP asked if the observable was running on the UI thread or the WebWorker thread. You've said that you assume it is running on the UI (main) thread. How do you come to that assumption? Also, what solution are you suggesting by passing the messages through a subject?

Comment: The OP wanted to push messages from a worker to the main thread using Rx. My assumption was that he was using postMessage to do that, which he confirmed. The solution allows him to subscribe to an observable on the Ui thread but still have messages sourced from a worker.

Comment: RxJS also has a `fromWorker` that takes the URL to your Web Worker: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/fromworker.md

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that Rx doesn't introduce concurrency unless you instruct it to via SubscribeOn, ObserveOn or some transform operator like Buffer.

So any code in the "Subscribe" part of the Rx operator will run in the same thread you called .Subscribe(onNext etc). However the actual callbacks onNext, onError and onComplete will run on whatever thread the observer uses, you don't control this (unless you wrote the operator).

To ensure you receive calls on the UI thread you should add a .ObserveOn(UIDispatcherThread). This will guarantee the thread you are called back on and make it testable.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, communication between calling code and webworkers is serialized and so you cant send something that has behavior (such an observable) over the wire.

I've written a little helper that uses Rxjs to help resolve this and other pains of developing with webworkers. Read about it [here](https://medium.com/@asi_73084/using-web-workers-synchronously-sort-of-dd70c8ead56a), github repo [here](https://github.com/asiFarran/webworker-commuter)